# Trying to override SoapHeaderAttribute to add Authentication to the attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

I'm stucking use a legacy .net 2.0 .asmx web services (tried to convince them to switch to WCF but no luck there). I'm trying to find a way to not only use a custom SOAP header, but also to authenticate the user without having the authentication code in each link.

Currently, my web service looks like this:

```
    public WebserviceAuthentication currentUser;

    [WebMethod(Description="Returns the logged in users credentials")]
    [SoapHeader("currentUser")]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        var user = AuthenticateUser(currentUser, WebServiceResources.MEDICAREELIGIBILITY_HELLOWORLD);
        return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", user.User.UserName, user.User.ProviderUserKey, user.AccountId);
    }
```

Ideally, I'd change the code to the following:

```
    public WebserviceAuthentication currentUser;
    public CustomAuthentication user;

    [WebMethod(Description="Returns the logged in users credentials")]
    [SoapHeaderAuthentication("currentUser")]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", user.User.UserName, user.User.ProviderUserKey, user.AccountId);
    }
```

SoapHeaderAuthentication would read the currentUser and confirm that the information is a registered user. if they are, return the custom user object and populate the user object. I could then access the user object from within the WebService.

The problem is, I can't extend the SoapHeaderAttribute because it's a sealed class.

Comment: Possibly. Do you have an example?

Comment: Not really.  I just know I was able to get a lot more control over the header with WSE in a recent implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going back a bit, but I wrote an article that you could extend: [here](http://nickbutler.net/Article/SoapSizeExtension)

Comment: So I've combined what you wrote and what is listed in this article: http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/article.php/c5479. So far, I have the authorization working, but don't have access to the CustomAuthentication object from my webservice. Also, trying to figure out how to pass a value from my attribute to the extension method.

Comment: Ok. So I've got the attribute passing a parameter now, but still can't figure out how to access the CustomAuthentication object from the webservice. Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [`SoapExtension` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx) to learn about the only extensibility mechanism in ASMX web services which will permit you to get control on every request (or response).